# Redirect request to a specific https address only through VPN (OSX)

Tags: macos, vpn, cisco-vpn-client, osx-mountain-lion

I would like to use my company's VPN only to manage my emails via exchange (https). Which means I have to redirect the traffic going to https://mail.company.com through my VPN but not the other addresses.

If I go to Network Preferences -> Advanced -> Proxies I see we can bypass proxy settings for a list of hosts and domains, but I want to do the other way: use the proxy only for a list of domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short version:
You can add a route for a specific host.

Long version:
If you only use https://mail.company.com/ for this task then you can change the routing table to route **all** request for this host via a specific interface. In this case via the VPN.

Using the shell the command for this would be something like thing:
`route add -host IP_from_mail.company.com IP_of_VPN_gateway`
Replace IP_from_mail.company.com with the IP of mail.company.com. If you do not know which IP that is try `ping mail.company.com`.

This should work until your next reboot.

To add it permanently you need to do some things which I can not test due to a lack os OS/X on my part. Googling seems to point to `sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/setstaticroute.plist`. However this is untested by me since I have no OS/X

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But it seems that it not the only problem that I have: my company is the child company of another one. When the proxy is on, I can resolve *.company.com but not *.mom_company.com. And the server is on https://email.mom_company.com. Would you know what I can setup to be able to resolve email.mom_company.com ? I can setup my email to use the IP address of email.mom_company.com, but Exchange will change it back to a name that I can't resolve anymore without all traffic going through https. I hope I am clear enough...